# Looking for efficient python program for this following python script

Tags: python

I am looking for a memory efficient python script for the following script. The following script works well for smaller dimension but the dimension of the matrix is 5000X5000 in my actual calculation. Therefore, it takes very long time to finish it. Can anyone help me how can I do that?

```
def check(v1,v2):
    if len(v1)!=len(v2):
        raise ValueError,"the lenght of both arrays must be the same"
    pass
def d0(v1, v2):
    check(v1, v2)
    return dot(v1, v2)
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
vector=[[0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], [.23, .18, .56, .61, .12], [.9, .3, .6, .5, .3], [.34, .75, .91, .19, .21]]
rav= np.mean(vector,axis=0)
#print rav
#print vector
m= vector-rav
corr_matrix=[]
for i in range(0,len(vector)):
    tmp=[]
    x=sqrt(d0(m[i],m[i]))
    for j in range(0,len(vector)):
        y=sqrt(d0(m[j],m[j]))
        z=d0(m[i],m[j])
        w=z/(x*y)
        tmp.append(w)
    corr_matrix.append(tmp)
print corr_matrix
```

Comment: Your vectors don't happen to have a lot of zeroes in them, do they? If so, check out the scipy sparse package...that can save you quite a bit of trouble. Also, you know that the correlation matrix is (necessarily) symmetric, so you can cut out some of your looping using that fact. You can also cut out another N for loops because the main diagonal should be all 1's.

Comment: The problem isn't how much memory you're using (I guess you have at least a gig or two RAM), it's the algorithm (and Python) that is slowing you down. You can use Ben's suggestions to improve the algorithm and try to make vector a numpy array and use numpy operations for your algorithm to get a huge speed increase.

Comment: Also your dot product is performing too many checks, something like 2N^2 + N, when you could be doing N-1 checks instead with something like `[check(vector[i], vector[i+1]) for i in range(len(vector)-1)]`. But this is just because I'm bored, and waiting for a script to finish, not because it will change your execution speeds drastically.

Comment: @gnibbler: If he's trying to store a 5000x5000 matrix as a Python `list`, and he has a gig or two of RAM, he's using almost all of his RAM for that matrix. So the problem could very well be how much memory he's using.

Comment: @abarnert, your estimates are way off. for 32 bit python there is 20k per list. 20k*20k is only 400MB.

Comment: @gnibbler: Even if there were no overhead, how could 5000 64-bit `float`s possibly fit into 20K? I suspect you're just measuring the size of the `PyObject` pointers, and not the actual objects pointed to. (Either that, or you just tried to measure the difference between "interpreter before allocating anything" and "interpreter after allocating 5000 floats", not considering the fact that there's a bunch of space pre-allocated so you don't have to malloc each object.)

Comment: @abarnert, my bad. The floats will take 600MB, so That's a whole GB

Comment: @gnibbler: Does that 600MB also count the 25M pointers to the floats, which is another 100MB minimum? Anyway, looking at what the docs say needs to be there, we're talking 8 bytes for the double, 8-40 for `PyFloat` overhead, and 4-8 for the pointer, so somewhere between 500MB (32-bit, no alignment/padding, all debugging disabled) and 1400MB, so my 1600 was a bit off… but not much. And I don't think it's reasonable to assume nobody will ever be using a 64-bit Python in 2013. I'd guess that something like 99% of Mac users, 75% of linux/BSD/etc. users, and 25% of Windows users are already there.

Comment: @abarnert, the 600MB is just for the floats. I thought the list overhead should be 400MB, but now I've measured it on a 64 bit machine - it uses 856MB total. Lots of people are using 64bit (yay!) - just not many people with 2GB or less of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `matrix` (and your `vector`) into numpy `array`s instead of Python `list`s. That will make it take much less memory (and also run faster).

To understand why:

A Python `list` is a list of Python object instances. Each one of these has type information, pointers, and all kinds of other stuff to keep around beyond just the 8-byte number. Let's say each one ends up being 64 bytes instead of 8. So, that's 64 bytes per element, times 25M elements, equals 1600M bytes!

By contrast, a numpy `array` is a list of just the raw values, together with a single copy of all that extra information (in the `dtype`). So, instead of 64 * 25M bytes, you've got 8 * 25M + 64 bytes, which is only 1/8th the size.

As for the speed increase: If you iterate over a 5000x5000 matrix, you're calling some code in the inner loop 25M times. If you're doing a numpy expression like `m + m`, the code inside the loop is a few lines of C code that get compiled down to a few dozen machine-code operations, which is blazingly fast. If you're doing the loop explicitly in Python, the inside of that loop has to drive the Python interpreter every time through the loop, which is much, much slower. (On top of that, the C compiler will optimize the code, and numpy may have some explicit optimizations too.) Depending on how trivial the work inside the loop is, the speedup can be anywhere from 2x to 10000x. So, even if you have to make things a bit convoluted, try to find a way to express each step as an array broadcast rather than a loop, and it will be much faster.

---

So, how do you do that? Simple. Instead of this:

```
corr_matrix=[]
for i in range(len(vector)):
    tmp=[]
    # …
    for j in range(len(vector)):
        # …
        tmp.append(w)
    corr_matrix.append(tmp)
```

Do this:

```
corr_matrix=np.zeros((len(vector), len(vector))
for i in range(len(vector)):
    # …
    for j in range(len(vector)):
        # …
        corr_matrix[i, j] = w
```

That immediately eliminates all the memory problems caused by the overhead of keeping around 25M Python `float` objects, and will give you a significant speed boost too. You can't reduce the memory any further except by not keeping the whole `array` in memory at once, but you should be fine already. (You can boost the speed even more by using broadcast operations in place of loops, but if the memory is your problem, and the performance is fine, it may not be necessary.)

Comment: Can you share a script for this?

Comment: I'm not going to write your whole program for you, but I'll give you some examples.